# How to resolve Xcode errors from Firebase when building on watchOS Swiftui canvas

Tags: firebase, swiftui, apple-watch, firebase-analytics, swift-package-manager

I installed Firebase using swift package manager and am running into an annoying problem. Whenever I use the watchOS swiftui canvas to preview a view, I get a number of Xcode errors from GoogleAppMeasurementWithoutAdIdSupportTarget, FirebaseAnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport, FirebaseAnalytics, and some others.

The error messages include "While building for watchOS Simulator, no library for this platform was found in ..." and "The package product 'GULAppDelegateSwizzler' requires minimum platform version 6.0 for the watchOS platform, but this target supports 2.0"

Does anyone know how to fix all these errors that keep popping up? These errors only occur when the watchOS Swiftui canvas is used.

Answer (score 0):

GoogleAppMeasurementWithoutAdIdSupportTarget, FirebaseAnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport, and FirebaseAnalytics are not supported for watchOS targets and should be excluded.  More details at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4557

Comment: Do you have any details on how to exclude them so Xcode Previews work? I don't have Firebase in the targets for my watchOS app, and it builds fine on a regular device, but I can't use Xcode Previews. Using Firebase 10.0.0 with Xcode 14.0.1.